# Formulating an optimisation problem into a mixed-integer problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

[image]

I'm not sure if I understand this question and was wondering if anyone could provide any insight to an answer. The only thing I can think of adding is a constraint: "x2 = integer", so I'm clearly missing something. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a Linear Mixed Integer Programming, replace the second constraint by
$$
4x_1+4(y_1+3y_2+4y_3+10y_4)\ge 10\\
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=1\\
y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4 \in \{0,1\}
$$

With $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=1$, you force exactly one term of the sum $y_1+3y_2+4y_3+10y_4$ to be active. The active term is precisely $x_2$.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense!

Comment: I did haha, unfortunately I don't have enough credits for them to be visible!

Comment: @parag note that the second constraint of the formulation is precisely $x_2 \in \{ 1,3,4,10\}$ and not $\{ 0,1,3,4,10\}$.

Comment: Which means X2 cannot be 0. However, please see that X1 and X2 are greater than OR EQUAL TO ZERO.

Comment: Infact , saying y1+y2+y3+y4 = 1 , is equivalent f saying X2=1.

Comment: @parag When there are multiple constraints, the feasible region is the intersection, so $x_2 \ge 0$ is redundant: $\{1,3,4,10\}\cap [0,\infty)=\{1,3,4,10\}$.

Comment: I understand now what you are saying. Thank you.

Comment: HI @RobPratt I see what you are saying. But, there is a concern here. both of these constraints are part of the problem ( See it is mentioned that , $x_2 \ge 0$ and $x_2$ can take $1,3,4,10$. While what you are saying is absolutely true. But, when a complex problem comes, judging from question set-up and formulating question is difficult as compared to directly writing whatever conditions are provided ( atleast for starters, may be like me )

Comment: @parag The $x_2\ge 0$ bound is redundant and should have been omitted from the problem statement for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

A special case of integer variables are binary variables. The second constraint can be reformulated as

$y_1\cdot x_2+\frac{1}{3}\cdot y_2\cdot x_2+\frac{1}{4}\cdot y_3\cdot x_2+\frac{1}{10}\cdot y_4\cdot x_2=1$

$y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4\in \{0,1 \}$

Comment: You´re welcome.

Answer (score -2):

This is also a correct formulation.
$$
4x_1+4(y_1+3y_2+4y_3+10y_4)\ge 10\\
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4\le 1\\
y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4 \in \{0,1\}\\
x_1 \ge 0
$$

$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 1 $ ( avoiding  $x_1 \ge 0 $ ) also works as mentioned previously due to redundant constraints.

Comment: Here, $x_1$ is a continuous variable. And $x_2$ can either be $0$ or $1$. Thus making your problem a mixed-integer linear programme or MILP

Comment: I dont know, how come people are negatively voting this. This is also a correct formulation. Can someone tell me how come it is wrong?

Comment: If $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 0 \le 1$, then $x_2=0$, which is not feasible, as you need $x_2 \in \{1,3,4,10\}$.

Comment: This is exactly the thing, I have problem with. In the original problem, it is written that $x_2 \ge 0$. Then, how do we neglect the condition of $x_2 =0$?

Comment: I strongly feel that the problem is semi-integer in nature. i.e. $x_2.lo = 0$ and also $x_2$ can take other discrete values mentioned. Otherwise, why would they write $x_1, x_2 \ge 0$